Holomorphic function with $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
Let $\mathit{U}=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}\ \mid \mathfrak{Re}(z)>0\}$. I was trying to come up with an example of a non-constant holomorphic function $f:\mathit{U} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=0; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and I came up with the example $f(z)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{z})$ that is holomorphic as it's the composition of differentiable functions on $\mathit{U}$ $\quad (f(2)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$).
But now if I wanted to extend the domain to $\mathbb{C}$, it wouldn't be possible as $0$ is a accumulation point of the points of the form $(\frac{1}{n},0)$ so $0$ would be also a zero of the extended function and by identity's theorem, $f \equiv 0$.
Are these conclusions alright?

Yes, the conclusions are correct. Infact, $0$ is an essential singularity.

Sorry, I haven't come across the classification of singularities; what is the proper definition of an essential singularity?
